# Allow floats to be null values in mySQL

Tags: mysql, null, geocoding

I'm having a problem with my geocoding script where it inserts null values into the mySQL database and breaking my script because my `coord_lat column cannot be null`. When I take a look at my structure, it tells me that null values are allowed. Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you declare the column, remove the `not null`.

Comment: according to that screenshot, it's already not null.

Comment: That's the thing. It says not null but my script tells me the coord_lat column can't be null which is weird.

Comment: Are you looking at the *same* database/schema? And the *same* table? If so then that error should not be raised.

Comment: are there any triggers on that table that try insert/update into another table, that DOES have the constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the column using `alter table`:

```
alter table modify coord_lat float not null;
```

However, the column was declared to be `not null` explicitly, so I don't know if this is a good idea.  I guess the bigger question is why you are inserting a row without this information.

Comment: This will not break my existing records correct? Just want to double check, thanks!

Comment: it won't. but its not a terrible habit to make sure you have a recent backup before making any changes

Comment: This contradicts the OPs posted 'current scheme' .. something is amiss.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was a different table that didn't allow null values.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is an index that covers this column, those can also force columns to be non-null. (Note: Could be simple or composite.)

Answer (score 0):

Worthy of note is that you must explicitly specify that you want the field to be null. The default for float will always be 0.00 (with as many decimal places as the field).

```
INSERT into GEO (city,lat,lng) VALUES ('london',null,null);
```

if you just leave out the lat and lng

```
INSERT into GEO (city) VALUES ('london');
```

then lat and lng will be 0.00000

I usually store lat/lng values as a string as converting them to float is a simple thing to do when needed.